# No workspaces in Activities overview after updating to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, workspace-switcher, activities-overview

When going to *Activities* overview after update to Ubuntu 20.04, I can't see workspaces and so I can't drag and drop windows between workspaces.

[image: screenshot of desktop]

I have 4 static workspaces configured. List of enabled and installed GNOME Shell extensions:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions
[
'user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'dim-on-battery@nailfarmer.nailfarmer.com',
'systemMonitor@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com',
'alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca',
'dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com',
'dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com',
'gpaste_integration@awamper.gmail.com',
'GPaste@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org',
'wsmatrix@martin.zurowietz.de',
'ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com',
'noannoyance@sindex.com',
'native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'multi-monitors-add-on@spin83',
'launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com',
'apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com'
]

$ ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
dim-on-battery@nailfarmer.nailfarmer.com
drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
multi-monitors-add-on@spin83
native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
noannoyance@sindex.com
places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
wsmatrix@martin.zurowietz.de
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling "Horizontal workspaces" extension solved the issue.

I also use Workspace Matrix which does the same + more, so this extension was redundant anyway.